# VS 2017 - Missing NuGet Package from an old solution project

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am working on an old project that was given to me. When I try to build, I get the following error:

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\WinSCP.5.13.0\build\WinSCP.targets.   App1.App.Export C:\Visual_Studio\App1.App.Export\App1.App.Export\App1.App.Export.csproj
```

1. I looked at the NuGet Settings and it is set to download automatically any missing Nuget Packages.
2. I also tried removing and re-installing the missing package in the NuGet Manager.
3. Clean the build and rebuilt the project.
4. Right-clicked on the Solution and selected 'Restore NuGet Packages

What other methods should I try?

Comment: Edit your question and include the relevant part of your project file that references this package. Based upon the error message, it looks like the package is being installed from a local directory. You can go to nuget.org to download the package manually or (better) change the project to use nuget.org as the source. This link might help you with a manual installation on your system: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install

Comment: First,you should make sure that the nuget package exists on the [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/).  Then, try to close VS,delete `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`. Then, reopen your project, run `update-package -reinstall` under `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`Package Manager Console`.

Comment: If you have a workaround, it is kind of you to add it here.

Comment: Hi Peter, any update about thus issue? Please let us know if my answer works for you. Also, if my answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to accept it. If not and you have any concern, please fee free to let us know and we will willing to help you further.

Comment: Please let us know any progress.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have missed the nuget package [WinSCP 5.13.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinSCP/5.13.0).

Please try these stpes:

**First of all**, the package exists under `nuget.org`, so you should make sure that the `nuget.org` is under your nuget package source and the checkbox is checked.

[image]

**1)** [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`.

**Also**, delete `bin` and `obj` folder.

**2)** close VS, delete `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`.

**Then**, reopen your project, run `update-package -reinstall` under `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`Package Manager Console`.

**3)** If it still cannot work, please try to create a new project and then install `WinSCP 5.13.0` nuget package to see whether it works.

**Also**, share the whole csproj file with us so that it will help us troubleshoot the issue more quickly.